# SoundCloud SDK not receiving token callback in production environments, in Safari only

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm wondering if this is a bug with a new SC SDK release that has gone out. Everything was working fine until of late.

To replicate:

- open Safari
- go to: http://mixmatic.io
- login and look at the local storage from Mixmatic for auth. It will be null.

Do the same in Chrome and it will be correctly populated.

To further test, once authed on Chrome and Safari, head into the console and type:

```
SC.accessToken();
```

Chrome will return the token, Safari will return null.

Could you please investigate this bug?

Comment: @ whoever voted to close, please note that on dev.soundcloud.com they explicitly point to post the SO for problems with their code. I know that this is incorrect usage of SO, but this is not my choice.

Comment: Im also experiencing this issue.

Our usage can be seen in: https://github.com/MoodCat/MoodCat.me-Frontend/blob/master/app/scripts/services/audio/soundCloudService.js

I also opened an issue on Github: https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/issues/19#issuecomment-113445035

I have put a bounty on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/MoodCat/angular-soundcloud . I ended up in rewriting the Soundcloud SDK for angular / router purposes. Maybe you can benefit from it, it seems you are using Angular as well.

Comment: I by the way think that it is related to ui-router. Because it transforms the href, the Soundcloud API is unable to read the oauth token from the query parameters. Do you have a routeProvider.otherwise('/') set? You might want to test to let the soundcloud dialog navigate to another html page having just the soundcloud js file.

Comment: Yup I'm using otherwise! So a quick fix would be to try removing that? I don't get how this has suddenly broken..

Comment: Im not sure if it's a quick fix for the Soundcloud SDK, but it was a finding of me while reimplementing their SDK again in angular. I found that I could not fetch the query param easily, but had to do this in a early stage (module.configure or so) and had to just split all location.href parameters by #, &, and ? to eventually get the accessToken out of it.
(Because ui-router replaces /?auth_... with /#/auth